# DB2 Update with subquery that contains join - correlating

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to perform an update with a subquery  where the update table is joined in the subquery.  I cannot figure out how to associate the update record with the record found in the subquery.  Something like the following, though as written this will obviously update the entire table.  Thanks in advance.

```
Update OPTION OPT
SET (PSTREET, PCITY, PPROVINCE, PCOUNTRY, PPOSTALCODE)=
(select ADDRESS, CITY, PROVSTATE, COUNTRY, POSTALCODE
from ADDRESSES  addr INNER JOIN COMPANY C ON C.SECURITYCOMPANY = addr.CODE1 || addr.CODE2
    INNER JOIN DCODE D ON C.COMPANY_ID = D.COMPANY_ID
    INNER JOIN OPTION OPT ON OPT.DCODE_ID = D.DCODE_ID
WHERE C.YEAROF IS NULL
AND C.DELETED IS NULL
AND D.DCODEEFF < CURRENT TIMESTAMP
AND (D.DCODEEXP IS NULL OR D.DCODEEXP > CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
AND D.DCODEELEMENT = addr.DCODEELEMENT
AND D.IND = addr.IND
AND ((addr.IND = 'B' AND addr.VAL1 = OPT.VAL1 AND addr.VAL2 = OPT.VAL2) 
  OR (addr.IND = 'Y' AND addr.VAL2 = OPT.VAL2) 
  OR (addr.IND = 'X' AND addr.VAL1 = OPT.VAL1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some criteria to identify the records in OPT that you want to update. If its a single record, you'll need a surrogate or natural key. If its a many records like, say, based on a timestamp, you will need that time. Those criteria can then be put into a where clause after your set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a condition in the WHERE clause in the sub-query that  ties the result(s) in the sub-query to the outer table that you're updating. Here I added **`AND addr.addr_id = OPT.addr_id`** to your `WHERE` clause, but whatever the id column is called it needs to be shared between the table that you are updating and the sub-query.

```
UPDATE OPTION OPT
SET (PSTREET, PCITY, PPROVINCE, PCOUNTRY, PPOSTALCODE) =
    (SELECT ADDRESS, CITY, PROVSTATE, COUNTRY, POSTALCODE
     FROM ADDRESSES addr INNER JOIN COMPANY C ON C.SECURITYCOMPANY = addr.CODE1 || addr.CODE2
                         INNER JOIN DCODE D ON C.COMPANY_ID = D.COMPANY_ID
                         INNER JOIN OPTION OPT ON OPT.DCODE_ID = D.DCODE_ID
     WHERE C.YEAROF IS NULL
           AND C.DELETED IS NULL
           AND D.DCODEEFF < CURRENT TIMESTAMP
           AND (D.DCODEEXP IS NULL OR D.DCODEEXP > CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
           AND D.DCODEELEMENT = addr.DCODEELEMENT
           AND D.IND = addr.IND
           AND ((addr.IND = 'B' AND addr.VAL1 = OPT.VAL1 AND addr.VAL2 = OPT.VAL2) 
                OR (addr.IND = 'Y' AND addr.VAL2 = OPT.VAL2) 
                OR (addr.IND = 'X' AND addr.VAL1 = OPT.VAL1)
           AND addr.addr_id = OPT.addr_id)
```

In reality the criteria might be more complicated (involving a compound key or some inequality condition, for instance) - but regardless, adding the condition to the inner query is what's required.